# Looking for data mining project idea

Tags: web, data-mining

I know this question may be not appropriate for SO, but I'll try.

I need a topic for course project in data mining. It should be done in 1 month and it should have a web output.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kaggle](http://www.kaggle.com/competitions) has many competitions where you will find interesting data mining problems. You can choose one from there or make a simpler version of one of those problems you project.

It also helps to look at different sources of data, like the [UCI Repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html). Look at different datasets that are available and think what classification, prediction or inference can be made from the available data.

Note: you might want to clarify what you mean by 'web output'. If you meant the system output will be visible from a website, you can just have a server serve pages that shows the results. You can have an [online learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning) system that is continuously scanning new data and changing predictions (or other outputs). Then have a have a website that fetch the results and displays it realtime.